# Merge Sort creates stack overflow

Tags: vb.net, mergesort

I cant understand why this merge sort is causing a stack overflow. Is it because I have no base case and if so, how would I go about adding it? The merge sort is pretty advance for a beginner like me :( so I would appreciate any help or advice.
Additionally, I am having trouble understanding where data is stored once you split the array recursively. I understand that splitting the original array breaks it down into individual elements, but where are these individual elements stored??

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Array() As Integer = {5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6}
    Dim right As Integer = Array.Length - 1 'find right index
    Dim left As Integer = 0 'set left index
    mergeSort(Array, left, right)
End Sub

Sub mergeSort(Array, left, right)
    Dim middle As Integer
    If left < right Then
        middle = (left + right) / 2

        'recursively split both halves of the array
        mergeSort(Array, left, middle)
        mergeSort(Array, middle + 1, right)

        'sort individual elements
        mergeSortedArray(Array, left, middle, middle + 1, right)
    End If
End Sub

Sub mergeSortedArray(ByRef Array, left, middle, rbeg, right)
    Dim pt As Integer = 0
    Dim TempArray(6)

    While (left <= middle) And (rbeg <= right) 'sort every element
        If Array(left) < Array(rbeg) Then
            TempArray(pt) = Array(left)
            left += 1
        Else
            TempArray(pt) = Array(rbeg)
            rbeg += 1
        End If
        pt += 1
    End While

    If left > middle Then
        While rbeg <= right   'left sub array exhausted 
            TempArray(pt) = Array(rbeg)
            rbeg += 1
            pt += 1
        End While
    Else
        While left <= middle   'right sub array exhausted 
            TempArray(pt) = Array(left)
            left += 1
            pt += 1
        End While
    End If

    For Each element In TempArray
        Console.WriteLine(element & " ")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely because you recall the recursive function with the `mergeSort(Array, left, right)`, probably that statement should be `mergeSort(Array, left, middle)` or something similar :) (So inside the Sub mergeSort, you are recalling the function with the exact same parameters)

Comment: Ahh 1 up for spotting a flaw. Will amend code but it still causes an overflow

Comment: True, because in some cases left and middle are also the same, only call them if middle is not right, and if middle + 1 is not left. I deleted my post because well, your code has quite a lot of other flaws, that I think you need to work on a bit longer ;)

Comment: Thank you - I will go back to the drawing board and reformulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problems with this code. A merge sort in VB would look more like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Array() As Integer = {5, 33, 3, 10, 2} 'make the array

    'Split Array: you need the leftmost index & rightmost index
    Split(Array, 0, 4)
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

Sub Split(Array, left, right)
    If left < right Then 'if the array has elements..
        Dim middle As Integer = (left + right) \ 2 'find halfway point 

        Split(Array, left, middle) 'split left array 

        Split(Array, middle + 1, right) 'split right array 
        'recursion keeps on splitting the two arrays until we have a bunch of single elements

        'now sort and merge
        Merge(Array, left, middle, right)
    End If
End Sub
Sub Merge(ByRef Array, left, middle, right)

    Dim SizeA As Integer = middle - left + 1
    Dim SizeB As Integer = right - middle
    Dim LeftArray(SizeA) As Integer 'set size of left array.
    Dim RightArray(SizeB) As Integer 'set size of right array

    'Left & Right pointers to keep track of what elements in the array we are referring to
    Dim LP As Integer
    Dim RP As Integer

    For LP = 0 To SizeA - 1
        LeftArray(LP) = Array(left + LP) 'assign 0 index of original array to left hand array (5)
    Next

    For RP = 0 To SizeB - 1
        RightArray(RP) = Array(middle + 1 + RP) 'assign 1 index of original array to right hand array (33)
    Next

    'reset pointers
    LP = 0
    RP = 0
    Dim i = left 'set a pointer for the original array

    'swap elements if need be:
    While LP < SizeA And RP < SizeB
        If LeftArray(LP) <= RightArray(RP) Then 'if element in left array is smaller that the one in the right
            Array(i) = LeftArray(LP) 'assign the left value to the original array
            LP += 1 ' increment the left array's pointer
        Else
            Array(i) = RightArray(RP) 'otherwise the original array gets the right element
            RP += 1 'increment the right array's pointer
        End If
        i += 1 'now increment the counter for our new array
    End While

    'Hang on...what if there are still elements in the left array
    While LP < SizeA
        Array(i) = LeftArray(LP) 'assign these elements to the new array
        LP += 1 'increment the left pointer
        i += 1 'increment the new array's pointer
    End While

    'Hang on...what if there are still elements in the right array
    While RP < SizeB
        Array(i) = RightArray(RP) 'assign these elements to the new array
        RP += 1 'increment the right pointer
        i += 1 'increment the new array's pointer
    End While

    'write out the new array
    For Each element In Array
        Console.Write(element & " ")
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("")
    'start the second pass
End Sub
```

Comment: You should explain what the problems are and why your code solves them.

Comment: hoped the annotations would suffice